# Отображение имени потока python в мониторе процессов

Tags: python

Необходимо в реалтайме отслеживать каждый поток python-процесса.
В Python'е есть возможность задать имя потока:

```
Thread(name='Test')
```

И в htop есть возможность отображать пользовательские имена потоков (F2 -> Display options -> Show custom thread names).
Но пользовательские имена потоков все равно не отображаются. Вместо них указано название интерпретатора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, где я неправ? Может быть есть другие средства мониторинга каждого потока процесса?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В классе Thread аргумент name служит только для нужд самого python, например когда вы делаете print.

Для установки имени нужно вызвать prctl:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def set_name(name):
    from ctypes import cdll, byref, create_string_buffer
    libc = cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
    buff = create_string_buffer(len(name)+1)
    buff.value = name
    libc.prctl(15, byref(buff), 0, 0, 0)

def test():
    set_name(b'SomeThread')
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

t = Thread(target=test, name='TestName')
print(t)
t.start()
```

В htop будет вот так (запускал из ipython, поэтому есть еще другие thread без имени):
[image: Вот так выглядит в htop]

Comment: Спасибо! Вот уж не думал, что в Python'е так костылить придется..

Comment: Сложно сказать, костыль это или нет. Вроде не сильно востребованная возможность. Если тот же htop посмотреть, мало у кого заданы произвольные имена для тредов.

Comment: Соглашусь с Вами. Библиотека [python-prctl](https://pythonhosted.org/python-prctl/) - обертка над системным prctl. И задать имя уже проще: `prctl.set_name(name)`
Set the process name for the calling process, the name can be up to 16 bytes long. This name is displayed in the output of **ps** and **top**. The initial value is the name of the executable. For python applications this will likely be python.